# Initiate an Ajax call from a jQueryMobile application

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to make an Ajax call from a jQuery Mobile application. The call is served properly by the destination server. However, the browser rejects the response.

Firefox says:

```
x: [object Object], m: error, e: [Exception... "Component returned failure
code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"
location: "JS frame :: file:///path/to/my/page/resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
:: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 4"  data: no]
```

And Chrome says:

```
x: [object Object], m: error, e: Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101
Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

My understanding is this error is linked to a cross domain call issue. I have done all what I have found in jQuery and jQueryMobile documentation with no luck.

My page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Main Page</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />

    <script src="./resources/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).live("mobileinit", function(){
        jQuery.support.cors = true ;
        jQuery.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true ;
    });
    </script>
    <script src="./resources/js/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        // the request
        jQuery.ajax({
            async:          false,
            contentType:    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            crossDomain:    true,
            data:           {data: "abcd"} ,
            dataType:       "text", 
            error:          function(x, m, e) {
                alert("x: " + x + ", m: " + m + ", e: " + e);
            },
            processData:    true,
            success:        function(data){
                alert("Received: " + data);
            },
            type:           "GET",
            url:            "http://my/servlet/url"
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="page1" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a id="btn1" data-role="button" onclick="send();" >Go!!!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you can try to open the demo from http://localhost.

Comment: @xiaohao, I didn't get you idea. Can you please provide more details? In the meantime, please pay attention that the page "Main Page" is being loaded from the file system while the servlet is reachable on a server.

Comment: you can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595515/xmlhttprequest-error-origin-null-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin, and maybe the solution is there

Comment: Issue solved by asking the server to append the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by asking the server to append the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' to the response. For people using Java EE, the solution is to add this line of code:

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

where response is an instance of HttpServletResponse.